# How to reset some attributes of fixture in each Unit Test?

Tags: python, pytest

Could anyone of you tell how to alter fixture in each Unit Test, please?

In the following example I'd like to:

- execute `start_driver()` only once - this is long running operation, therefore I initialize this fixture with `scope=session`,
- reset `driver.counter` to 0 in each Unit Test.

**Code:**

```
import pytest
import time

def start_driver():
    # some long running operations
    time.sleep(3)

def increment(driver):
    driver.counter += 1
    return driver.counter

class DriverInstance():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = start_driver()
        self.counter = 0

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def driver():
    yield DriverInstance()

def test_driver_1(driver):
    assert increment(driver) == 1

def test_driver_2(driver):
    assert increment(driver) == 1
```

**Pytest execution:**

```
$ pytest driver.py
========================================= test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /home/backend/backend, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: mock-1.10.4
collected 2 items

driver.py .F                                                                                     [100%]

=============================================== FAILURES ===============================================
____________________________________________ test_driver_2 _____________________________________________

driver = <driver.DriverInstance object at 0x7f78a5b000b8>

    def test_driver_2(driver):
>       assert increment(driver) == 1
E       assert 2 == 1
E        +  where 2 = increment(<driver.DriverInstance object at 0x7f78a5b000b8>)

driver.py:25: AssertionError
================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 3.03 seconds ==================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce another fixture that will reset the counter, for example

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def reset_counter(driver):
    driver.counter = 0
```

`reset_counter` will be executed automatically because of `autouse=True`, and because the default scope is `function`, it will be executed before each test once. The `driver` argument will reference the return value of the `driver` fixture (fixture args, just like test args, are resolved by fixture names also).

Comment: Glad I could help!